# SQLite and Python: table already exists, no such table

Tags: linux, database, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm learning **python web programming** and I'm studying on **database management** right now. I wrote two python file for database; one for **creating a table**, other for **inserting data** to it.
It seems two files run correctly without any error. But after creating table and inserting data to it, when I want to **SELECT** the table to see the result in **SQLite** I'll face the **error**: `Error: no such table: film`. Where the **film** is the table I've created.

---

### dbcreate.py

```
import sqlite3 as db
conn = db.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('create table film(title text, director text, year text)')
print "table created"
```

### dbinsert.py

```
import sqlite3 as db
conn = db.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('insert into film values("God Father","Francis Ford Copola", "1972")')
cursor.execute('insert into film values("The Shawshank Redemption","Frank Darabont", "1994")')
conn.close()
print "data inserted"
```

### SQLite

```
sqlite> select * from film;
Error: no such table: film
```

What is the reason?

Comment: You've got to call `conn.commit()` after creating the table.

Comment: And after the insert statements.

Comment: Still same error @bernie

Comment: In the sqlite shell are you doing `.open test.db`?

Comment: After inserting or before?

Comment: Doesn't matter. What I'm curious about is if you're viewing the right database in the shell.

Comment: I tried both but nothing changed. I have one database and it's `test.db`. Also when I enter `.tables`, SQLite shows nothing.

Comment: Note that the place where you open the sqlite shell should be the same place as `test.db` is located. Otherwise you need to specify the path to the database, e.g. `.open c:/mydir/test.db`

Comment: @bernie 1 good news and 1 bad. The good one is no error returned. And the bad is no result.

Comment: How do you start the sqlite3 CLI? What does `.databases` say? Boils down to: Check if you really, _really_ have attached the right DB file in the CLI.

Comment: `.databases` shows `test.db`. How should I attach a database?

Comment: If you see this it is already attached, usually as the main DB. But is it the right file with the right path? If you start the CLI with a filename, SQLite will simply create a DB file if it doesn't exist, which would lead to the symptoms you're seeing (no content in your DB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start the CLI with a filename, SQLite will simply create a DB file if it doesn't exist, which would lead to the symptoms you're seeing (no content in your DB).

What does `.databases` say? Boils down to: Check if you really, *really* have attached the right DB file in the CLI.

(Compiled the relevant parts of my comments into an answer to provide an acceptable answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all my friends for giving their helping solutions to me and specially thanks to **bernie** and **Murphy**. First of all I had a silly mistake: every time I called **sqlite3** on bash I was doing this: `sqlite3 test.db` which is creating a `test.db` file in `/sqlite3/`. So I tried `sqlite3 /path/to/test.db` and it worked. Then I should to `.open test.db` to see the result.Thank you so much. The problem is solved :)